# Is $\inf_{||x||=1}||T(x)||$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ be a linear function. Is the function $G: L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that maps $\displaystyle T \mapsto \inf_{||x||=1}||T(x)||$ a continuous function? Why?

My question comes from the fact that, if this is a continuous function, then it provides an easy way to prove that the injective linear maps are an open subset of the linear maps, since they are $G^{-1}(~(0,\infty)~)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\parallel S-T\parallel < \varepsilon$ Then
$$ \inf_{\parallel x\parallel =1}
 \parallel Tx\parallel =\inf_{\parallel x\parallel =1}
 \parallel (T-S)x + Sx\parallel  \leq
 \inf_{\parallel x\parallel =1 } \{
 \parallel (T-S)x \parallel + \parallel Sx\parallel \}
 \leq  \inf_{\parallel x\parallel =1 } \parallel Sx\parallel  +
 \varepsilon $$

So by similar argument,
$$ \inf_{\parallel x\parallel =1}
 \parallel Sx\parallel
 \leq  \inf_{\parallel x\parallel =1 } \parallel Tx\parallel  +
 \varepsilon $$

So continuous.